# Fineuploader and MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, upload

I try to implement [Fineuploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) in my MVC4 project but it always fails to upload. What i did:

added css and js files to my view:

```
<link href="~/Content/fineuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/js/util.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/button.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/dnd.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.base.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.form.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.xhr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/header.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-plugin.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/js/uploader.basic.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/uploader.js"></script>
```

added the code for the upload button and exceution of the script (i think this isn't right?)

```
<script>
    function createUploader() {
        var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: '/Upload/UploadFile/'
            }
        });
    }

    window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
```

added the C# files to my project `FineUpload.cs`, `FineUploadResult.cs` and the Controller `UploadController.cs`. I also added a route to the controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "upload",
                    url: "Upload/UploadFile",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Upload", action = "UploadFile" }
                );
```

The controller is:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload, string extraParam1, int extraParam2)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

But `UploadFile` is never called on the server.

Comment: Try replacing `url: "Upload/UploadFile"` with `url: "/Upload/UploadFile"` in your endpoint

Comment: i did, but the controller isn't executed. I added the route at the beginning. Maybe it has to do with the parameters in the action?

Comment: Yes. Can you give a try like this: `public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload, string extraParam1="", int? extraParam2=0)`

Comment: No success: it always routes  to another controller /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...

Comment: i added the example code for large files of fineuploader to my web.config file. This was the problem for the routing! Now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have messed up your script inclusions (order and everything). You should choose whether you need to use the FineUploaderBasic mode, the FineUploader mode or the jQuery plug-in mode. Given your code you seem to be using the standard mode.

Here's a full working example and the minimal markup:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/fineuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fine-uploader">Click me to upload a file</div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/js/header.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/button.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.base.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.form.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/handler.xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/uploader.basic.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/dnd.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/uploader.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createUploader() {
            var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
                debug: true,
                request: {
                    endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Uploader")'
                }
            });
        }
        createUploader();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also your controller action seem to be taking some extra integer parameter. If you do not specify it with the request, this request will obviously fail. Use a nullable integer in this case.

Comment: My controller action still isn't executed? I added the routing add the beginning of `RegisterRoutes`

Comment: What routing? You don't need to be adding any routing for this to work. Just use the Default route. Get rid of your custom route. Also look at FireBug to see what request is being made to the server and what does the server respond to that request.

Comment: i have to add a specific route, because it routes to another controller /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...  I think my routing is false now? Please look at my question. I have added routing and controller.

Comment: Oh wait a minute. Does your target controller action requires the user to be authenticated? Is it decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute? Also which web browser are you using to test this? But to answer your question: you don't need any routing at all. The default should be sufficient. Also your controller action seem to be taking some integer parameter but nowhere in the request you have specified a value for this parameter meaning that your action will never be invoked because the default model binder will crash telling you that a required parameter `extraParam2` was not supplied.

Comment: as you can see in my question i have no `[Authorize]` atrribute at my `UploadController`. I use chrome. I try deleting `extraParam2` but have still the routing issues.

Comment: What do you see in the `Network` tab of your Chrome Developer toolbar? Could you please show the request and response being sent to your server? Also have you tried the code exactly as shown in my answer? I guess you haven't because this code works fine.

Comment: i added the example code for large files of fineuploader to my web.config file. This was the problem for the routing! Now it works.